# Parametrized JUnit: Loading multiple property files from String array

Tags: java, properties, junit, parameterized-unit-test

I am trying to write a test that loads different properties files from String array. But the code keeps throwing a null pointer exception, any ideas please?

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class AllTests 
{ 
     private static String text;
     private static Properties props;

     public AllTests(String text) 
     {
        AllTests.text= text;
     }

     @Parameters
     public static List<String[]> data() 
     {
       String[][] data = new String[][] { { "test.properties" }};
    return Arrays.asList(data);
     }

         @BeforeClass
     public static void setup()
     {  
           props = new Properties();
         try 
         {
            //load a properties file 
        props.load(new FileInputStream(text));
         } 
         catch (IOException ex) 
         {
        ex.printStackTrace();
         }
 }

 @Test
 public void test() 
 {
        System.out.println(text);
 }}
```

I did some further investigation and discovered the @Test stub works but the @BeforeClass returns null, can I not use the parameters in the setup?

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class AllTests 
{ 
     private static String client;
```

`public AllTests(String client) 
 {
    AllTests.client = client;
 }

 @Parameters
 public static Collection<Object[]> data() 
 {
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { "oxfam.properties" }};
   return Arrays.asList(data);
 }

 @BeforeClass
 public static void setup()
 {  
     System.out.println(client);
 }

 @Test
 public void test() 
 {
        System.out.println(client);
 }}`

Comment: props.load(new FileInputStream(client)); this the line that throws the null pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brent says, the original error was because props wasn't initialised. However, the reason your test doesn't work is because you're using static fields. They should be instance fields, only the `data()` should be static.

The following works:

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class AllTests {
  private String text;
  private Properties props;

  public AllTests(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    props = new Properties();
    try {
      // load a properties file
      props.load(new FileInputStream(text));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Parameters
  public static List<String[]> data() {
    String[][] data = new String[][] { { "test.properties" } };
    return Arrays.asList(data);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println(text);
  }
}
```

JUnit calls the `data()` method and then creates an instance of the `AllTests` class for each value returned by the `data()` method, with the constructor parameters which also come from the `data()` method. Therefore your text and props fields should be instance fields.

So in your example, your `@BeforeClass` was called before the constructor, hence the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

The `props` class variable is never initialized.  Try initializing it on declaration:

```
private static Properties props = new Properties();
```

Comment: @DavidCunningham Then text is null.